# Which license to use for a template that you cannot modify (structure) and must attribute, but which can be used freely : fill with data, images...?

Tags: license, copyleft

What license to use for a template ?
As an example, let's say an MS Access template.
I want people to use/share it but only to store data, commercially or not, but isn't it a 'modification' of the original 'file' (MS Access is kind of a file...)?
I also want attribution for the work.
And I don't want people to fork my template.

Comment: How do you distinguish a filled-out and used template from a modified one? Disallowing derivatives puts your question out-of-scope for this site.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: A database structure and the contents stored in the database are two independent things. If you don't want people to change the structure, don't call it a template. Just call it a database that they can store their own data in.

Answer (score 2):

The freedom to modify is one of the fundamental requirements of open source, so *in the context of this site*, the answer is "no such license".